# Advantages of intel oneAPI versus the older Parallel Studio XE (Fortran user)

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, intel-oneapi

I program numerical models to solve Partial Differential Equations in Fortran, in serial and parallel (with MPI). Only Fortran, I do not know/need other languages. I see I now need to migrate to Intel OneAPI, before I had Parallel Studio XE 2019. Any advantage/new feature after migrating to OneAPI that a Fortran average user will enjoy? I never used GPUs, will OneAPI make the transition easier if in the future I wanna learn how to parallelize the code and run it on GPU?

Comment: OneAPI is the future of Intel compilers. If you use modern language features, they are better than the previous Studio. I know about this mostly in C++, but I guess the same will hold for F18 features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no necessity for a transition to speak about. You will get the same `ifort` you had before, just an updated version. And an option to try the new (LLVM-based) `ifx`, but it is just an option, I did not use it yet either.

The `ifort` compiler is the same compiler you are used to, just updated to (as of now) version  2021.2 with various small improvements and bug fixes as always with their new version.

If you do want to try new `ifx`, it indeed comes with new GPU features. Only the `ifx` compiler supports GPU offload. See [Get Started with OpenMP* Offload to GPU for the Intel® oneAPI DPC/C++ Compiler and Intel® Fortran Compiler (Beta)](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-cpp-fortran-compiler-openmp/top.html)